# How do I print an array without the first term?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program to open up links based on a command entered into a console. The command is "/wiki >term array<", and it will open up a web browser with the wiki open and the term array sent through the search function of said wiki.

Here is my current code for building the term array to send to the search field:

```
SearchTerm = Arrays.toString(StringTerm).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");
```

Now, all that does is get all terms passed the word "/wiki" in my slash command and prints them into a list. It also removes commas and square brackets to make what it prints cleaner.

-- I want to add a specific parameter for the first term in the array, so if it is a specific code such as "/wiki wikipedia chickens" is entered, it will send the user to wikipedia with the term "chickens" searched instead of the default wiki with the terms "wikipedia chickens" searched.

Using the current code that I have to build the term array I need to use Arrays.toString in order to print the whole array in a readable fashion, but I don't want it to print the first term in the array after it passes through my keyword filter?

When I use this code:

```
WIKI_HYPERLINK = WIKI_WIKIPEDIA + StringTerm[1] + StringTerm[2] + StringTerm[3] + StringTerm[4] + StringTerm[5];
```

It uses array terms 1 - 5, but if there are only 3 entered terms it will throw an error, and if there are more than 5 it will throw an error.

So my question is: How do I get a whole array excluding the first term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `StringBuilder` in a loop

```
//  StringBuilder with initial String
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(WIKI_WIKIPEDIA); 
for (int i=1; i < stringTerm.length; i++) {
   builder.append(stringTerm[i]);
}
String searchTerm = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I can manage with this code. I didn't think of using a for loop in order to put the strings from my array into one big line, but then again I am a very new programmer.

But I have one more question: What part of the code removes the first term in the array?

Comment: The loop start at index `1` - that's the 2nd element in the array, i.e. (it doesnt actually remove it, just skips it)

Comment: OH, and I can just put this in an if statement, right? if(StringTerm[0] == "wikipedia") { for loop }

Comment: You need to use `String#equals` for comparing `Strings` the `==` operator compares Object references. `if ("wikipedia".equals(stringTerm[i])) {`

Comment: Oh alright, thanks. There are so many rules with strings that I didn't know about. You helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
String outputString = "";
for (int i = 1; i < StringTerm.Length; i++)
    {
        outputString += StringTerm[i];
    }
```

You may also be able to use a `for each` loop if there is something like `if (Array.Element != 0)` in Java, but I don't know of one. Just edit the code above to get it in the format you need.